# nested for loop that changes numbers between 1 and 0 and keeps changes them as you keep going through the loops

Tags: r

I'm trying to do two for loops that would code the first 100 as 1, then it would turn every second number as 0, like 2,4,6 etc, then every third, so 3 would be zero but because 6 is 0 it has to go back to 1. and then every fourth number and so on until it reaches 100 and it will change 100 to either 0 or 1 depending what was before that.

this is the idea: what the loop is supposed to do

[image]

```
status <- 1

for (b in 1:100) {
  for (e)
}
```

this is as far as I got, I know it's not much but I really did try. Any help is welcomed, like another post similar to this, what I can google to help me, or helping me solve it.

Comment: Just to clarifty, the 50th iteration should pick 50 and 100. What about from there on? The 51st iteration picks just the 51st element, 52nd iteration picks just the 52nd element and so on?

Comment: yes, sorry if I didn't explain it well enough.

Comment: No worries, the comments here doesn't let me format the code well, I posted it as an answer instead...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
 temp = rep(TRUE, 100)
 for(i in 2:100) {
    print(as.numeric(temp))
    temp[seq(i, 100, i)] = !temp[seq(i, 100, i)]
 }
 print(as.numeric(temp))
```

Just to illustrate that this works for a set of 10 numbers:

```
temp = rep(TRUE, 10)
for(i in 2:10) {
    print(as.numeric(temp))
    temp[seq(i, 10, i)] = !temp[seq(i, 10, i)]
 }
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0
1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0
1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0
1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1
1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1
1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1
1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1
1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1
1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0
```

Comment: yes thank you! if you don't mind could you explain why its 2:100 and not 1:100 and whats this code temp[seq(i, 10, i)] = !temp[seq(i, 10, i) saying. I get some of it but I am a little confused and would like an explanation on what it saying.

Comment: Yeah, so, the first step creates a vector if 1s. Then the values at indexes 2,4,6,...,100 are flipped, followed by flipping values at indexes 3,6,9,... and so on. The seq() function gives these indexes that need flipping at each step of the iteration. The ! operator simply tells to flip the values at those indexes and replace them. It's not too hard to follow, it might help to run individual parts of the code to better understand what goes on...

Comment: My pleasure, please accept my answer if it helped you :)